# What Happens If MySQL Server Restarts During Trigger Process

Tags: mysql, triggers, crash, restart

Let's assume that there is a MySQL server running and there is a series of MySQL triggers in progress.

Let me give an example. (just an example to explain what i mean by trigger series, if there is a logic error please neglect)

We got table1, table2, table3 on our server.

table1 has after insert trigger, does something like;

```
UPDATE table2 SET name = 'x' WHERE id='15'
```

table2 has an after update trigger, does something like;

```
INSERT INTO table3 (id,name) VALUES ('15','x')
```

table3 has after insert trigger, does something like;

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id = '15'
```

Now let's say our code on client side has send an insert command on table1 to start this trigger chain. And before this chain is finished the server that our MySQL server installed on is restarted by an IT Personal or closed/crash. What happens in this situation?

Would MySQL just rollback any changes done by triggers or would our data end up in disarray?

Or, for restarting part, would it hold the restart command until the processes are finished?

I want to know all cases but if I must be specific, let's say MySQL is working on a Windows Server.

And as for the last question, if our data ends up in disarray, is there any way to prevent it from happening without giving up on triggers?